# What is the meaning of "Major Update backward-incompatible updates" when using Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg, spfx, sharepointframework

I'm using Yarn and when I installed my packages, I wanted to update them. I am really new to this so I having trouble understand what each one meaning.
An explanation would be helpful as I am not getting it from Googling.

(I am using this to install and working with SPFx).

`yarn outdated v1.17.3 outdated
info Color legend :
 "<red>"    : Major Update backward-incompatible updates
 "<yellow>" : Minor Update backward-compatible features
 "<green>"  : Patch Update backward-compatible bug fixes`

**Edit:** - Finally think I understand..
red = Major Update. The updates are NOT backward-compatible.
yellow = Minor Update. The updates have backward-compatible features.
green = Patch Update. The updates are just patches to fix bugs, and are backward-compatible.

Please correct if wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite correct. NPM packages use Semver (Semantic Versioning) to indicate a package version. The version number isn't merely just an incremented number, it tells you a bit about what happened with an upgrade.

So you will most of the time have a version numbers that look like 1.2.3 or (MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH), where:

1. MAJOR - Big changes that changes the way the package is used, so you might need to update how you use/call the corresponding package. The update is thus not backward compatible.
2. MINOR - New functionality was added to the corresponding package, your code doesn't have to change. The change is backward compatible.
3. PATCH - No features were added, patches normally include bug fixes or small optimisations to a package.

Sometimes there is more meta data in the version number, for example `1.0.0-rc.1`
indicates that this is a **Release Candidate**. Other examples include 1.0.0-alpha or `1.0.0-beta`.

You can read more on Semantic Versioning at https://semver.org/